# O que é SOA e quais as vantagens de seu uso?

Tags: soa

Li algumas definições na web, mas nenhuma conseguiu atingir um nível que me permita definir de forma clara o que é e quais as vantagens de SOA dentro de uma empresa.

**UPDATE**

Algumas das definições encontradas foram:

> a) SOA é um **estilo de arquitetura de software** cujo princípio
>   fundamental prega que as funcionalidades implementadas pelas
>   aplicações devem ser disponibilizadas na forma de `serviços`;
>
> b) Corresponde a uma **metodologia para desenvolvimento de software**,
>   `serviços`, representa todos ativos de softwares da empresa;
>
> c) É um **estilo de projeto** que guia todos os aspectos de criação e uso
>   de `serviços` de negócio através de todo o ciclo de vida de
>   desenvolvimento.

Existe uma forte tendência em acreditar, dadas as definições, que SOA está ligada de forma intrínseca a disponibilização de serviços, seu foco principal seja oferecer serviços.

**SOA é um estilo, uma metodologia, um processo, uma abordagem? Como definir sem ser imparcial a ponto de deixar dúvidas sobre o conceito?**

Comment: Acho que é uma hora excelente de atualizar o Wiki da tag SOA.

Comment: Olá Geison, como vai? Cara, para ser muito honesto acho difícil responder uma pergunta tão ampla no formato do Stack Overflow. [Essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english) (fechada) do SOEn possui boas tentativas, mas a verdade é que o escopo da pergunta é amplo demais para responder sem fazer generalizações um tanto quanto grosseiras.

Comment: Olá, @AnthonyAccioly. Acredito que por mais difícil que seja definir um termo, em função de seu nível de abstração ou complexidade, este possui uma definição ou várias e, portanto é factível de ser conceituado.

Comment: *"Li algumas definições na web"*, por favor, diga quais são e porque não lhe permitiram atingir tal nível. Nada mais chato que alguém dar uma resposta e ter que escutar, "ah, não, essa eu já conheço...". O legal é você por todas suas informações na mesa, assim não tem desentendimento.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que dois exemplos do mundo real podem fazer você entender um pouco melhor o porque isso é relevante. Alias, pra falar a verdade, quando li sua pergunta me interessei e fui pesquisar e vi que já trabalho com isso faz algum tempo e nem havia percebido. Como realmente nunca havia ouvido falar de SOA escrevi essa resposta mais pra tentar ajudar com algumas coisas que eu tenho percebido no meu trabalho e que acho que estão relacionadas. Peço àqueles que conhecem mesmo o assunto que me corrijam caso eu fale alguma besteira aí. Vamos lá:

### 1. Aplicações de Página Única (SPA's)

Hoje em dia existem diversas aplicações de página única por aí. O exemplo clássico é o gmail. Essas aplicações são marcadas pelo fato de ter uma interface criada pra web que é extremamente interativa e que não precisa ficar recarregando a página, ou seja, carrega-se grande parte da aplicação na primeira execução e as execuções posteriores servem pra receber recursos necessários em certos momentos.

Não vou discutir as vantagens e desvantagens de SPA's, mas basicamente pra fazer um SPA com qualidade você implementa duas coisas totalmente separadas: uma interface gráfica escrita com HTML/CSS/Javascript e um serviço web. O serviço web expõe de forma consistente todos os métodos pra realizar as manipulações sobre o domínio que sua aplicação precisa.

### 2. Aplicações WPF usando MVVM

Quando você desenvolve um aplicativo pra windows desktop usando WPF é comum você querer abordar isso com o padrão MVVM. Um jeito comum então de encapsular a lógica pra acesso a dados nessas aplicações é usar um serviço. Quando eu trabalhei com isso eu lembro que vi alguns tutoriais e livros e se usavam na época de serviços WCF. As razões são as mesmas praticamente dos SPA's.

### Vantagens

Com esse tipo de abordagem você consegue algumas coisas

1. Separação de conceitos bem feita: a interface sabe da interface, o servidor sabe do domínio. Mudanças de interface não afetam o domínio, e mudanças de domínio usualmente não requerem grandes mudanças de interface.
2. O mesmo serviço pode ser usado pra várias interfaces. Se você precisa usar os mesmos dados numa segunda interface (num site por exemplo, ou num aplicativo de celular), você pode requisitar o mesmo serviço. Novamente, mudar algo no servidor não requer mudar vários lugares.

Assim, além de você ter como compartilhar funcionalidades em vários ambientes distintos (basta eles saberem se comunicar via HTTP no caso dos serviços web), você consegue permitir que as responsabilidades de distintos componentes que compõe o seu sistema estejam bem definidas, de forma que você possa ter facilidade de manutenção.

Supondo que você desenvolva o seu serviço com orientação a objetos e que você consiga de fato construir ele com baixo acoplamento e alta coesão usando os princípios de orientação a objetos e tudo. Se você precisar mudar a lógica de acesso a dados, vai mudar em um só lugar, no servidor e todas as aplicações cliente sem nenhum tipo de mudança no seu código irão se beneficiar disso.

Se você mudar a forma que um tipo de domínio é implementado, a mesma coisa acontece. Em geral você consegue com isso reaproveitar muito código, permitir uma portabilidade muito maior e ter uma flexibilidade muito grande ao criar sua interface gráfica.

No caso de serviços web, imagine que `api.meuservidor.com/clientes/` seja uma URL que aponta para um recurso capaz de devolver uma lista de clientes. Ao construir a interface isso é tudo que você precisa saber pra renderizar uma lista de clientes. Como os clientes são implementados, como eles são armazenados, ou etc, não é necessário saber. Se você trabalha em uma equipe e existe um programador responsável pela interface gráfica, isso vai facilitar bastante a vida dele.

Em resumo, implementar as reais funcionalidades da sua aplicação que lidam com os tipos de domínio e etc em uma camada de serviços permite reduzir acoplamento, aumentar o reuso de código e facilitar a manutenção da sua aplicação. Dessa forma, o SOA é uma metodologia, como você mesmo disse, um estilo de arquitetura, que te instrui a ter no seu software uma camada de serviços pra poder ter todas essa vantagens entre outras.

### Referências

[Service-Oriented Architecture - Wikipedia PT](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)

[Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) Definition](http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/web-services/service-oriented_architecture_soa_definition.html)